# THREE.JS - Reflections in the windows of a building

Tags: three.js, blender

I created a building with Blender and imported it in three.js. I managed to give the windows of the building a semi-reflective effect with a cube camera and this line:

```
geometry.materials[3] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, ambient:0x0000aa, envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget, reflectivity: 0.7, refractionRatio: 0.25 } );
```

geometry.materials[3] is the Blender material for my windows. Problem is, that this building I created, is a skyscraper and it happens to have plenty of windows. If I do it like above, I get the same reflection in every single window, because there are other materials between the windows and every window-material is isolated from the next window-material by the wall-material. But I would like to have one big reflection over all windows, like if the whole building was only made out of one material. The reflection should only appear in the windows and not on the walls. Windows are all the same material. Is there a way to archieve this behaviour?